# Bootstrap selectpicker not working when added dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, tabs, bootstrap-selectpicker

I'm trying to dynamically add new tabs by appending Html code (div with content).
I'm doing so by:

1. creating a div with the tab content, which includes amongs all (bootstrap) **SelectPicker**

   ```
    <div id="main_div">
        ...
        <label for="title" class="label-heading"> First Name </label>
        <select multiple class="form-control" name="last_name" id="last_name"
        </select>
        ...
    </div>
   ```
2. Afterwards - I get the div HtmlElement, by using the getElementById and its innerHtml

   ```
   var tabs = $("#container").tabs();
   ..
   ..
   var div_content = document.getElementById("main_div").innerHtml;
   ```
3. Then - appending the Html element (the innerHtml seen in secrion 2) to the tabs.

   ```
   tabs.append(div_content);
   ```

The problem is that by doing so, it seems that the controls **SelectPicker** and datepicker functionality malfunction - selecting item from the drop down (in SelectPicker) - doing nothing.

Have any idea why bootstrap controls (selectPicker and DatePicker) does not work inside the tab?

Thanks.

Comment: Run SelectPicker on the newly-created elements after they've been created

Answer (score 2):

You need to refresh the selectpicker after you add it:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
```